# Error "generate features" with ArcScan vectorization

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, vectorization, arcscan

Windows 10, ArcGIS 10.4.1/ArcScene 10.4.1.5686

I have a geotiff that I pulled in from a pdf. I'm in an edit session of ArcScan and when I Show Preview, the output looks great. However, whenever I try to Generate Features, I receive the following error:

> The map does not contain an editable polyline layer. Please add one and try the command again.

Any suggestions to proceed with ArcScan?

Comment: Does your map "contain an editable polyline layer"?

Comment: I'm trying to create a polygon layer from a raster, that's what ArcScan vectorization does. So no, unless I'm misunderstanding something, why would I have an "editable polyline layer" if that is what I am trying to create? This thread regards the same question (https://geonet.esri.com/thread/22940), though doesn't seem to have ever been answered. Thanks.

Comment: The answer at that GeoNet thread was `The reason is quite simple: with the vectorization generates lines, it will also need another shapefile of the 2line" type, not "polygon" type. At the same time, if you use only a "line"-type shapefile and the vectorization generates polygons, it will ask for a polygon shapefile type also.` i.e. exactly what I am saying in my answer and alluding to in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should review the help [About automatic vectorization](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcscan/about-batch-vectorization.htm) (with my **bolding**):

> ArcScan supports centerline and outline vectorization methods in
>   automatic mode. **The centerline vectorization method allows you to
>   generate vector line features** at the center of the raster cells. This
>   method is the most common type of vectorization. The centerline
>   vectorization method is the default setting. The outline vectorization
>   method allows you to generate vector polygon features at the borders
>   of the raster cells.

You do not specify whether you are using the centerline or outline vectorization method so I suspect that it is the default of centreline.

To generate polygons you either need to use the outline vectorization method or post-process the line features from the centerline method to create polygons from them.

Comment: I'm using the centerline method. I am specifically trying to avoid "outline vectorization" (that happened when I outsourced my difficulties to a friend who used Adobe Illustrator). I am stuck at "Generate Features" or Step 7 from here (http://gisgeography.com/how-to-vectorize-image-arcscan/). In other words, I'm not able to "post-process" anything because I can't seem to figure out how to make it run in the first instance. When I hit "Generate Features," it throws me the error that I quoted in the original post. I created a blank feature class, not shapefile, I will try blank shapefile now...

Comment: @Chris_80 Your question would be improved with a precise description of the steps that you performed beginning with Start ArcMap.

Comment: Sounds good. 1. New project, load band 1 of 3-band tiff, classify into 2 values; 2. Create new polyline shapefile and set coordinate system; 3. start editing and 4. VOILA! Thanks, it seems that I really did need to create _polyline shapefile_, not a polygon feature class, which is what I initially tried (and, in fact, what the error told me to do all along...how embarrassing).

Answer (score 1):

Its really simple. I just needed to add a polyline shapefile, as the error told me to do and PolyGeo originally said - not a polygon feature class or anything else.