# Doing automatic vectorization in ArcMap?

Tags: raster, arcmap, vectorization, arcscan

[image]I'm using ArcMap 10.6; ArcScan. I am trying to run an automatic vectorization on my .tif file. I've cleaned up my raster, and am doing Start Editing - Vectorization - Show Preview (looks good) - Generate Features ... and this is where it has the progress bar, like it's creating them, and my map 'refreshes', yet... nothing is in my line layer.

I have both a parcelline and parcelpolygon layer, both are file geodatabase feature classes. They are what I select when Generating Features. When I Start Editing, I'm selecting my file geodatabase that contains those two layers.

I've tried all the trouble shooting I know -- I even tried creating a shp file for the lines, like another post recommended, but to no avail. Help?

I believe my tif falls in the same spatial domain. This was the previous post [Error "generate features" with ArcScan vectorization](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254161/error-generate-features-with-arcscan-vectorization) mentioned.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What GIS software are you using?

Comment: There is an [edit] button beneath your question that you should use to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Does your TIF fall within the spatial domain of your geodatabase feature class?

Comment: Could you show us your screenshot  of what you doing ?

Comment: I assume that you are also using ArcScan, so I've added a tag for that.

Comment: You said that you "even tried creating a shp file for the lines, like another post recommended".  Can you include a link to that other post, please?